# How to forbid running two copies of one postgresql pl/sql function

Tags: postgresql

I have heavy pl/sql postgres function. How to forbid starting another copy of this function.

Comment: Advisory locks come to mind: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/explicit-locking.html#ADVISORY-LOCKS

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options.

1. Advisory locks.  Pros: fast, lightweight, don't block others.  Cons: a pain to manage as they persist across transactions.
2. Semaphore tables.  In this you have a series of rows, which get locked by various functions to prevent concurrent execution.  Cons:  Slower, heavier-weight, and may interfere with writing to these tables.  Pros:  Easier to manage, released when transaction commits.